# How to get my saga finder to execute?

Tags: nservicebus, saga

I have a sager finder that looks as follow and I put a break point on the first line of the Findby method, but it never seem to execute. Is there something else that I need to do?

```
public class MySagaFinder : IFindSagas<UncorroboratedCreateNewUser>.Using<FoundUser>
{
    [Dependency]
    public ISagaPersister Persister { get; set; }
    [Dependency]
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public UncorroboratedCreateNewUser FindBy(FoundUser message)
    {
        var data = Persister.Get<UncorroboratedCreateNewUser>("CorrelationId", message.CorrelationId);
        if (data == null)
        {
            Bus.Return(0);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, it would be better to implement IHandleSagaNotFound.

Comment: Thanks Udi, but I'm still trying to understand when FindBy gets executed and if I could put a break point there.